# Largest eigenvalues of AA' equals to A'A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with proving that for any real matrix,the largest eigenvalue of AA' equals to the largest eigenvalue of A'A

Comment: The cleanest way to see this is to take the SVD of A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $m \times n$ and $n \times m$ matrices $A$ and $B$, the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same. Namely, if $AB v = \lambda v$ with $\lambda \ne 0$ and $v \ne 0$, then $Bv \ne 0$ and $BA(Bv) = B(AB v) = \lambda B v$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue, then for "generic" initial vector $v_0$, we have $(AA')^nv_0\approx \lambda^nv_0$. Now use that $(AA')^{n+1}=A(A'A)^nA'$

Comment: Why not use the equality, given an eigenvector $v$ instead of an approximation? And you don't even need $n$: if $AA'v=\lambda v$ then $A'AA'v=\lambda A'V$ thus $A'v$ is an eigenvector of $A'A$ for the same eigenvalue.